# Integral check. Is partial fractions the only way?

Tags: integration

I'm getting a different answer from wolfram and I have no idea where. I have to integrate:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{xdx}{(2x+1)^3}$$

Is partial fractions the only way?

So evaluating the fraction first:

$$\frac{x}{(2x+1)^3} = \frac{A}{2x+1} + \frac{B}{(2x+1)^2} + \frac{C}{(2x+1)^3}$$

$$x = A(2x+1)^2 + B(2x+1) + C$$

$$x = A(4x^2 + 4x + 1) + 2Bx + B + C$$

$$x = 4Ax^2 + 4Ax + A + 2Bx + B + C$$

$$x = x^2(4A) + x(4A+2B) + A + B + C$$

$4A = 0$ and $4A+2B = 1$ and $A + B + C = 0$ so $A = 0$ and $B=\frac{1}{2}$ and $C = \frac{-1}{2}$

Is the partial fraction part right?

So then I get:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{xdx}{(2x+1)^3} = \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(2(2x+1)^2)} - \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{2(2x+1)^3}$$

for both, using $u = 2x+1$ and $\frac{du}{dx} = 2$ and $du = 2dx$ and $\frac{du}{2} = dx$, 
$$\frac{1}{4} \int \frac{du}{u^2} - \frac{1}{4} \int \frac{du}{u^3}$$

$$ = [\frac{1}{4} - u^{-1} - \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{-2} u^{-2} ]_1^3$$

I'm going the route of changing the limits to the new u and since $u = 2x+1$, when $x = 0, u = 1$ and when $x = 1, u = 3$. Is this the right path?

finally I get

$$[\frac{-1}{4}u^{-1} + \frac{1}{8}u^{-2} ]_1^3$$

I plug in numbers but I get a different answer than wolfram...

Comment: I can't see any mistake in your work. What's the answer given by wolfram?

Comment: They have 1/18 as the answer @ThomasShelby

Comment: Please recheck your calculations. I'm getting  $\frac1 {18} $ when I substitute the numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_0^1 \frac{xdx}{(2x+1)^3} = 
  \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{2(2x+1)^2} - \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{2(2x+1)^3}$$

### $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{dx}{2(2x+1)^2}:$

$\qquad u=2x+1,\ x=\dfrac{u-1}{2}, \ dx = \dfrac 12 du$

$\qquad \displaystyle \int \dfrac{dx}{2(2x+1)^2} = 
                      \int \dfrac{du}{4u^2} = -\dfrac{1}{4u}$

$\qquad x=0 \mapsto u=1, \ x=1 \mapsto u=3$

$\qquad \left[-\dfrac{1}{4u} \right]_1^3 = -\dfrac{1}{12} + \dfrac 14 = \dfrac 16$

### $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{dx}{2(2x+1)^3}:$

$\qquad u=2x+1,\ x=\dfrac{u-1}{2}, \ dx = \dfrac 12 du$

$\qquad \displaystyle \int \dfrac{dx}{2(2x+1)^3} = 
                      \int \dfrac{du}{4u^3} = -\dfrac{1}{8u^2}$

$\qquad x=0 \mapsto u=1, \ x=1 \mapsto u=3$

$\qquad \left[-\dfrac{1}{8u^2} \right]_1^3 = -\dfrac{1}{72} + \dfrac 18 = \dfrac 19$

$$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{2(2x+1)^2} - \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{2(2x+1)^3}
   = \dfrac 16 - \dfrac 19 = \dfrac{1}{18}$$

There is also another way to solve for $A, B$, and $C$.

$$\frac{A}{2x+1} + \frac{B}{(2x+1)^2} + \frac{C}{(2x+1)^3} =\frac{x}{(2x+1)^3}$$

$$A(2x+1)^2 + B(2x+1) + C = x$$

Let $x = -\dfrac 12$ and you get
\begin{align}
   C &= -\dfrac 12 \\
   A(2x+1)^2 + B(2x+1) - \dfrac 12 &= x \\
   2A(2x+1)^2 + 2B(2x+1) &= 2x+1 \\
   2A(2x+1) + 2B &= 1
\end{align}

Again, let $x = -\dfrac 12$ and you get
\begin{align}
   2B &= 1 \\
   B &= \dfrac 12 \\
   2A(2x+1) + 1 &= 1 \\
   A &= 0
\end{align}

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** Substitute $x=\tfrac12 u -\tfrac12$

---

**Addendum:** Your original problem was $\int_0^1\frac{x\; dx}{(2x+1)^3}$. For this substitution, compute:

*Integrand:* We have $x=\tfrac12 u -\tfrac12=\tfrac12(u-1)$, so
$$\frac{x}{(2x+1)^3}=\frac{\tfrac12(u-1)}{(2\cdot\frac12(u-1)+1)^3}
=\tfrac12\frac{u-1}{u^3}=\boxed{\tfrac12\left(u^{-2}-u^{-3}\right)}$$

*Differential:* We have $x=\tfrac12 u -\tfrac12$, so
$$dx = d\left(\tfrac12 u -\tfrac12\right)=\boxed{\tfrac12du}$$

*Limits of integration:* The limits for $x$ are $0$ and $1$, so we find the corresponding values of $u$:
$$x=0\implies 0=\tfrac12 u -\tfrac12\implies u=\boxed{1}$$
$$x=1\implies 1 = \tfrac12 u -\tfrac12 \implies u=\boxed{3}$$
So, replacing the integrand, differential, and limits with the boxed items above we have
$$\int_0^1\frac{x\; dx}{(2x+1)^3} = \int_1^3\tfrac12\left(u^{-2}-u^{-3}\right) \tfrac12du$$
$$=\tfrac14\int_1^3\left(u^{-2}-u^{-3}\right) du$$
$$=\left.\frac14\left(-u^{-1}+\tfrac12u^{-2} \right)\right]_1^3$$
$$=\tfrac14[(-\tfrac13+\tfrac1{18})-(-1+\tfrac12)]$$
$$=\tfrac14[-\tfrac{5}{18}+\tfrac12]$$
$$=\tfrac14[\tfrac{4}{18}]$$
$$=\boxed{\tfrac{1}{18}}$$

This is the *precise* procedure you should follow for any substitution. Don't take shortcuts.

Comment: You beat me to it.

Comment: If I go your way, I wind up with $\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{u^2} - \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{u^3}$ which is different than what I have at some point. I can't see my error.

Comment: Falling way short on the "why" and leaning heavily on the "check out this trick"...

Comment: This is not a "trick" but a recognition of the entire *idea* behind $u$-substitution: there's a $(2x+1)^3$ in the denominator and $x = (2x+1)'/2$ in the numerator, so it really is a good idea to make the substitution $u = 2x+1$ here.  Solving that integral by the method the OP proposed is extremely tedious by comparison.

Comment: It looks like your error is not computing $du$ correctly.

Answer (score 4):

You've computed the integral correctly, probably you made a mistake while substituting in the limits of integration. Everything else upto that point is correct.

> Is partial fractions the only way?

No single way is the only way, you have tons of ways to do this integral. Have a look at the following approaches.

1. **Manipulation and U-Substitution**

   - Make the substitution $\begin{bmatrix}t \\ \mathrm dt \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2x+1 \\ 2\mathrm dx\end{bmatrix}$
   - Use the General Power Rule for Integrals
     $$I=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{x \mathrm dx}{(2x+1)^3}\implies 2I=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{2x+1-1}{(2x+1)^3}\mathrm dx$$ $$2I=\int_{0}^{1}\biggl[\dfrac{1}{(2x+1)^2}-\dfrac{1}{(2x+1)^3}\biggr] \mathrm dx $$

$$\implies I=\dfrac{1}{4}\biggl[-\dfrac{1}{t}+\dfrac{1}{2t^2}\biggr]_{1}^{3}=\dfrac{1}{18}$$

---

2. **Trigonometric Substitution**

   - Make the substitution $\begin{bmatrix}x \\ \mathrm dx\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1/2\cdot\tan^2 \theta\\\tan\theta\sec^2\theta\mathrm d\theta\end{bmatrix}$
   - Use the Pythagorean Identity involving tangent and secant functions namely $\sec^2\theta=1+\tan^2\theta$ to get $2x+1=\sec^2\theta$.

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{x\mathrm dx}{(2x+1)^3}=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\dfrac{\tan^3\theta \sec^2\theta}{\sec^6\theta}\mathrm d\theta$$

Using the definitions of $\tan\theta=\sin\theta/\cos\theta$ and $\sec\theta=1/\cos\theta$. The integral simplifies to the following form: $$I=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\sin^3\theta\cos\theta\mathrm d\theta=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\sin^3\theta \cdot\mathrm d(\sin\theta)$$

Again use the General Power Formula for Integrals to get the following expression:

$$I=\dfrac{1}{8}\biggl[\sin^4\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{2x})\biggr]_{0}^{1}=\dfrac{1}{18}$$

To compute $\sin\arctan(\sqrt{2})$, make use of the following easy to prove identity: $$\sin\tan^{-1} x=\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

Answer (score 2):

A much much easier way to solve it is by using  integration by parts.

**Hint:** Take $u=x$, $dv = \frac{dx}{(2x+1)^3}$.

Comment: $u$ but then $dv$?

Comment: @manooooh What do you mean? I don't understand.

Comment: I am sorry, I understood that you used sub. My apologies.

Answer (score 2):

1) Observe:  $$x= \frac 12 \times \left ( (2x + 1) -1\right).$$

2) Use this to obtain $$\frac{x}{(2x+1)^3} = \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{(2x+1)^2} - \frac 12 \times \frac{1}{(2x+1)^3}.$$

3) Integrate to get

$$ \int \frac{x}{(2x+1)^3} dx  = -\frac{1}{4} (2x+1)^{-1} + \frac{1}{8} (2x+1)^{-2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to evaluate this integral. One of them is to consider the function
$$I(n;a,b)=I=\int_0^1\frac{xdx}{(ax+b)^n}$$
for $b>0$, $0\neq a>-1$, and $1,2\neq n>0$. First we multiply the RHS by $1=a/a$:
$$I=\frac1a\int_0^1\frac{axdx}{(ax+b)^n}=\frac1a\int_0^1\frac{ax+b-b}{(ax+b)^n}dx$$
$$I=\frac1a\int_0^1\frac{dx}{(ax+b)^{n-1}}-\frac{b}a\int_0^1\frac{dx}{(ax+b)^n}$$
Then we focus on $$J(n;a,b)=J=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{(ax+b)^n}$$
Sub.: $$u=ax+b\Rightarrow \frac{du}a=dx$$
$$x=1\mapsto u=b+a\\ x=0\mapsto u=b$$
thus
$$J=\frac1a\int_{b}^{b+a}\frac{du}{u^n}=\frac1{a(1-n)}\left[(b+a)^{1-n}-b^{1-n}\right]$$
And since 
$$I(n;a,b)=\frac1aJ(n-1;a,b)-\frac{b}aJ(n;a,b)$$
We have that
$$I(n;a,b)=\frac1{a^2}\left[\frac{(b+a)^{2-n}-b^{2-n}}{2-n}-b\frac{(b+a)^{1-n}-b^{1-n}}{n-1}\right]$$
And of course your integral is given by $I(3;2,1)=1/18$.

No partial fractions needed :)

PS: This even works for fractional values of $n$. Check it out [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eoqgtlcayu).